# Placing Comments on Deleted Question

Tags: discussion

I added a comment on this question here on Web Applications: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14522348/1536038

Minutes later it was completely vanished (deleted by user), only to find it on Stack Overflow.

*Should I have flagged it as off-topic, so that it's tractable here on Web Applications?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That question is separate from the one here on Web Apps. The user deleted the question, then reposted it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If I flagged it as off-topic, I (we) would have been made aware of this, because it was migrated.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - no. The only time you are notified of a migration is if a) it's your question or b) you have answered the question.

Comment: I'm learning by the day !! So, no sweat, question got deleted.